# AttributeError: module 'jaxlib.xla_extension' has no attribute 'DeviceArrayBase'

Tags: google-colaboratory, clip, jax, image-generation

I'm trying to run a Colab notebook for image generation with JAX and ran into the following error:

```
    WARNING:jax._src.xla_bridge:No GPU/TPU found, falling back to CPU. (Set TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0 and       rerun for more info.)

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

    <ipython-input-7-73b0723cc3af> in <cell line: 23>()
     21 import jax.numpy as jnp
     22 import jax.scipy as jsp
    ---> 23 import jaxtorch
     24 from jaxtorch import PRNG, Context, Module, nn, init
     25 from tqdm import tqdm

    3 frames

    /content/./jax-guided-diffusion/jaxtorch/monkeypatches.py in register(**kwargs)
     16             print(f'Not monkeypatching DeviceArray and Tracer with `{attr}`, because that method is already implemented.', file=sys.stderr)
     17             continue
    ---> 18         setattr(jaxlib.xla_extension.DeviceArrayBase, attr, fun)
     19         setattr(jax.interpreters.xla.DeviceArray, attr, fun)
     20         setattr(jax.core.Tracer, attr, fun)

    AttributeError: module 'jaxlib.xla_extension' has no attribute 'DeviceArrayBase'
```

I tried to solve this problem by using different JAX versions and every GPU Colab offers but couldn't find a solution. I'd really appricate any help on this!

Link to the nootebook---> [click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pw1PAqAlS0Mi6GBEzcRoRL3fTDUN-Gye/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

`DeviceArray` and related types were deprecated and removed in JAX v0.4.1 (See the [Changelog](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#jax-0-4-1-dec-13-2022)). It looks like the version of `jaxtorch` you are using is not compatible with more recent JAX versions. If there is no newer version of `jaxtorch` available, I would suggest trying to use it with JAX version 0.3.25 or older.

Comment: thank you for the answer!
I'm not sure if I'm getting this right. The first cell of code is supposed to install JAX version 0.2.25. I'm also getting an error when running this cell:

`ERROR: jaxlib-0.1.75+cuda11.cudnn805-cp37-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

but I can still proceed with the notebook. Sorry for forgetting about this additional error. I don't know much about code, so I tend to get confused with some simple considered stuff.

Comment: `cp37` means the wheel is built for Python 3.7. Colab's runtime currently uses Python 3.10.